# Separation of routes in express

Tags: node.js, express

To prevent having a long list of routes in my routes.js file, I have moved routes.js into a folder simply called routes, and renamed the file to index.js. I want to create multiple other files that define routes for different categories. Here's the code that I would think I need to write to accomplish that:

```
// index.js
var express= require('express');
var app = express();
var passport = require('passport');

app.use('/api/auth', require('./auth.routes')(passport));
...
```

I required the auth routes, so now I can use them like this:

```
// auth.routes.js
var router = require('express').Router();

module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
        ...
    });

    router.get('/me', function(req, res) {
        ...
    });
    ...
    return router;
};
```

When I do this, `require('express').Router()` is undefined, I'm not sure why. What's the proper way to separate these routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a folder: `routes`

In `/routes/index.js` :

```
var
  express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

router.use('/api/auth', require('./auth'));
router.use('/api/users', require('./users'));

module.exports = router;
```

In `/routes/auth.js` :

```
var
  express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  ...
});

router.get('/me', function(req, res) {
  ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

In `/index.js` :

```
app.use(require('./routes')); // it will read /routes/index.js and it will read another files and build routing
```

p.s. use passport checkings in `/routes/index.js` (or separately in nested routing files) as middleware between route and require part.

if You want to see real example check [this](https://bitbucket.org/num8er/nix/src/1ca484af35dd0e59f495d6a207858232b080c242/routes/?at=master)

Comment: This seems like just the right way to do it, but for some reason my router is undefined in index.js. I am using `router = require('express').Router()` but it just doesn't want to work.

Comment: Well uhh, this is embarrassing. I was using express 3. *facepalm*